# Can we add these words indicating subjectivity to the automatic question review score?

Tags: feature-request, subjective, review, algorithm

I've found a few words to search for that are pretty good at finding questions to down-vote or close-vote--good enough that it might be worth factoring them into the question score that determines if they should be reviewed:

- best
- easiest
- fastest

Other words that aren't *quite* as reliable, but worth considering:

- simplest
- quickest
- 'vs' would be pretty good as long as it ignored questions tagged with [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), and similar

Comment: The presence of these words does not necessarily indicate that the question is subjective.  And I'm getting a bit weary of seeing people hold up the almighty computer as the preferred solution to these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Robert - They're certainly no guarantee, but they appear to be decent predictors of sub-par content, which is what the review tab is all about, and the computers are still only assisting by putting them in front of people who will provide the solution.

Comment: these are some of the same title words that trigger the red "this question looks subjective and is likely to be closed" warning on the /ask page.. guess how many users read that?